# Make background image of a div appear slowly using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using following code to achieve appearance of div's background image appear slowly:

```
$('#stepOne').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $('.stepImage').css("background-image", "url(/Content/Images/Eligibility.png)");
    $('.stepImage').css("-webkit-transition", "1s all");
    $('.stepImage').css("-moz-transition", "1s all");
    $('.stepImage').css("-ms-transition", "1s all");
    $('.stepImage').css("-o-transition", "1s all");
    $('.stepImage').css("transition", "1s all");
        }).on('mouseleave', function () {
    $('.stepImage').css("background-image", "none")
        });
```

But to no avail. Can someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[You cannot transition a background image](http://w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties) so I would create an extra div that you can transition the opacity on instead.

The main idea is to position the container relative and then have your background element absolutely positioned to fill the container with a z-index of -1 to push it behind and then animate the opacity of that

```js
$('.hover').on('mouseenter', () => {
  $('.background').addClass('active');
}).on('mouseleave', () => {
  $('.background').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.test {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url(https://www.fillmurray.com/400/400) top left no-repeat;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.background.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hover">hover me</div>
<div class="test">
  <div class="background"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but if you notice, in my question, hover element is different than the background-image element.

Comment: @Oxin see comment below snippet about transitioning background image - was updating my answer when you commented and then my computer crashed - updated snippet with example

Comment: @I am sorry for that. I somehow achieved something like i wanted. I am pasting it in my answer. Please have a look. Thank You Sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#stepOne').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $('.stepImage').css("background-image", "url(/Content/Images/Eligibility.png)");                
    $('.stepImage').css("transition", "transform 2s ease");
    $('.stepImage').css("transform", "scale(0.75)");
}).on('mouseleave', function () {
    $('.stepImage').css("transform", "scale(1)");
    $('.stepImage').css("background-image", "none");
});
```